# FPS limit function

Tags: c++, animation, directx9

I try to cap the animation at 30 fps. So I design the functions below to achieve the goal. Unfortunately, the animation doesn't behave as fast as no condition checking for setFPSLimit() function when I set 60 fps (DirectX caps game application at 60 fps by default). How should I fix it to make it work?

getGameTime() function counts the time like stopwatch in millisecond when game application starts.

[image: getGameTime()]

```
// Called once at the start of the game
void initGameTime()
{
    // We need to know how often the clock is updated
    if( !QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER *)&ticksPerSecond) )
        ticksPerSecond = 1000;

    // If timeAtGameStart is 0 then we get the time since
    // the start of the computer when we call GetGameTime()
    timeAtGameStart = 0;
    timeAtGameStart = getGameTime();
}

//Called every time you need the current game time
float getGameTime()
{
    UINT64 ticks;
    float time;

    // This is the number of clock ticks since start
    if( !QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&ticks) )
        ticks = (UINT64)timeGetTime();

    // Divide by frequency to get the time in seconds
    time = (float)(__int64)ticks/(float)(__int64)ticksPerSecond;

    // Subtract the time at game start to get
    // the time since the game started
    time -= timeAtGameStart;

    return time;
}
```

With fps limit http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3VDOMqI6ic

```
void update()
{
    if ( setFPSLimit(60) )
        updateAnimation();
}
```

With No fps limit http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rg_iKk78ews

```
   void update()
    {
        updateAnimation();
    }

bool setFPSLimit(float fpsLimit)
{
    // Convert fps to time
    static float timeDelay = 1 / fpsLimit; 

    // Measure time elapsed
    static float timeElapsed    = 0;

    float currentTime = getGameTime();
    static float totalTimeDelay = timeDelay + getGameTime();

    if( currentTime > totalTimeDelay)
    {
        totalTimeDelay = timeDelay + getGameTime();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Not looking close enough to find or even clearly grok your problem (too much code, way too little explanation of what's wrong - a video or something would help), but you should not call your `GetGameTime` more than once per frame.  The illusion of motion works because the whole frame is a snapshot of a single instance, while your usage will treat different points during rendering as different points in time.  Might even be your problem, dunno.  Also, be wary about throwing those static variables around like they're going out of style; encapsulate a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I would apply this as a comment if I had that privilege.  Depending on what precisely timeGetTime() returns, you may run into some serious, and easily addressable floating point rounding errors.

Right now, your getGameTime function converts these int64's to floats, then divides, then subtracts.  The issue is you're losing precision in the lower digits where it really matters when you do this.  Try storing the int64 value you get at launch, rather than converting it and storing the float.  Then invert the order of your operations there.  The final product should look something like this:

```
float getGameTime()
{
    UINT64 ticks;
    float time;

    // This is the number of clock ticks since start
    if( !QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&ticks) )
        ticks = (UINT64)timeGetTime();

    // Subtract the ticks at game start to get
    // the ticks since the game started
    ticks -= ticksAtGameStart;

    // Now ticks is going to be a much smaller number
    // Divide by frequency to get the time in seconds
    time = (float)(__int64)ticks/(float)(__int64)ticksPerSecond;

    return time;
}
```

Again, with high enough framerate this could be causing more serious problems.  Even without that, you're likely losing some time, and the sum of your Delta-T's won't actually be equal to the time since execution.

Comment: Your solution lost precision and left only 1 decimal place. http://i453.photobucket.com/albums/qq253/ulti-killer/2-55.png~original

Comment: I don't entirely see how that's possible.  The big source of precision-loss should have been when you did (float)(__int64)ticks/(float)(__int64)ticksPerSecond, because the digits you care about are relegated to the (possibly-rounded-off) decimals.  Then, upon taking the difference, these possibly-rounded decimals are promoted to being the biggest digits.

Answer (score 0):

`getGameTime()` returns the time since the game started running, not the time since the last update.  I assume `timeAtGameStart` is some global constant created while the game is launched, what you want to use instead is a `timeAtLastUpdate` value.  This may not be perfect, but it should look more like:

```
void update()
{
    if ( setFPSLimit(60) )
    {
        timeAtLastUpdate = getGameTime();
        updateAnimation();
    }
}

bool setFPSLimit(float fpsLimit)
{
    // Convert fps to time
    static float timeDelay = 1000 / fpsLimit;  // assumes getGameTime returns milliseconds - you don't want to check 1/60 when it should be 1/60 * 1000

    if( getGameTime() - timeAtLastUpdate > timeDelay)  
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```